# Grounding of heatsink for SiC MOSFETS half-bridge

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, grounding, heatsink

I was working on SiC Mosfet half bridge for dual active bridge, Each half bridge has two SiC MOSFETS Rds0n=0.035 mohm , the bus voltage peak is 600VDC on the primary side. and I was wondering should I ground the heatsinks' two pins to mitigate the noise from the switching node?

The heat sink for two TO-247 packages for two SiC Mosfets: [here](https://www.ohmite.com/assets/docs/sink_c.pdf?r=false).
And two thermal pads on each Mosfets [here](http://tds.loctite.com/tds5/Studio/ShowPDF/BERGQUIST%20SIL%20PAD%20TSP%201600S-EN?pid=BERGQUIST%20SIL%20PAD%20TSP%201600S&format=MTR&subformat=HYS&language=EN&plant=WERCS).

Thanks in advance.

[image: Dual active bridge]

Comment: You need to check the datasheet to see if the heatsinks tabs are electrically connected or not.

Comment: How many pF do you expect and what CdV/dt does that translate to and what resonant frequency and Q is the result?  100pF? If in doubt measure it. If too much make it a snubber with a small series R to gnd.

Comment: Sure you can, it would provide also some safety measure in case the insulation breaks, for example you could install a temperature sensor with less risk,